# Null Pointer exception in a retrieving directory path

Tags: java, android

I'm receiving error reports for an app in Google Play. The problem is that its very obfuscated 
 and I can't retrieve a lot of information from the stacktrace due to the proguard configuration:

The method where the app is crashing is:

```
private File getExternalStorageAppRoot(Context ctx) {
    String basePath="cache";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        File extFile = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(basePath);
        if (extFile != null) {
            return extFile;
        }
    }

    String externalFilesDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator
            + ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName + File.separator + "files";

    return new File(externalFilesDir, basePath);
}
```

The exception is a NullPointerException and ctx is always not null. Any ideas about where it is crashing?

In my tests this method does not crash

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what SDK level the system is running that experiences the crash?

Comment: Not really, the app is receiving about 15 crashes per week at this point

Comment: Is there any chance that the NPE is happening in another method? ProGuard's retrace sometimes offers several suggestions for a stack entry.

Comment: It's also worth checking whether `getExternalStorageDirectory()` can return `null` if the device is in mass storage mode (connected to a computer via usb).

Comment: My device does not return null at this method when the media is unmounted but it is possible! I'll check. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you method I would check the result of:

```
 ctx.getApplicationInfo() // and .packageName
```

and

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() // and .getAbsolutePath()
```

From my point of view just this two points could throw a NPE. Maybe you could do that printing some log outs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but none of those methods are suppoused to return null right?

Comment: this both methods are the unique reason in this method to throw your NPE, if not one of these, its not this method that is throwing the NPE. It's more likely the second case (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`).